# the url not working in Laravel 5.4 route

Tags: laravel, url, routes

Newbie to Laravel. In my project, my base url is 'http://localhost/laravel'. In my webpages I got a welcome page.
When I run

```
Route::get('/','UserController@index');
```

It works. 
Also

```
Route::get('/',function(){echo 'Succeed.';});
```

I can see the Succeed.
When I change it into "foo" inside, everything fails.
neither

```
Route::get('/foo','UserController@index');
```

nor

```
Route::get('/foo',function(){echo 'Succeed.';});
```

It returns the NotFoundHttpException

My controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
class UserController extends Controller
{
    // controller version, combined with route
    public function index(){
        return view('welcome');
    }
}
```

Also I got welcome.blade.php inside the views.
Any suggestions for this problem?

Comment: clear laravel cache and then try again using `php artisan cache:clear`

Comment: what error you get after using /foo ?

Comment: guys. It seems I change the filename server.php into index.php.......When I change it back to server.php everything runs fine. But in this case I have to go "http://localhost/laravel/public". Any ideas that I can go to the welcome page when I type "http://localhost/laravel" ? Thank you all for helping me about this question!

Comment: sometime due to view caches, try this one `php artisan view:clear` and `php artisan config:cache` then try

Comment: go to your project public directory and copy all files and place outside the public directory

Comment: go to your index.php which you copy out of public directory as i mentioned in my last comment and Change **line 22** to `require __DIR__.'/bootstrap/autoload.php';` and **line 36** to `$app = require_once __DIR__.'/bootstrap/app.php';`

Comment: @PrinceLuo you got my point ?

Comment: @blue moon      actually I don't want to change the construct of the framework anymore. As you see, I change one file name, and something go wrong then. I suppose if I change anything that is different from the origin, errors may occur. I prefer the way that could rewrite the base url that points to http://localhost/laravel

Comment: dear that's the right way and according to framework standards you should try once every application that exclude public from url use the same approach.@PrinceLuo

Comment: need to copy whole public directory one step back in main directory and then need to changes index.php as i mentioned above

Comment: Instead of `/foo` try only `foo` and please make  sure that `.htaccess` file exists in your root directory...

Comment: @blue moon     What will happen if I just put the index.php and the ,htaccess, the two files into the top root, but the rest remains?

Comment: it will not load styles etc

Comment: @blue moon If I keep the rest, can I add any code that tell laravel that reference the css or js from the /public/css and /public/js?

Comment: If you are using linux or Macos move the project to anywhere and create a symbolic link for the public directory into the public web server directory, I don't know in windows if shortcut will work, And i suggest using `Laravel Valet`

Answer (score 0):

If you have moved your index.php and .htaccess from public folder to root folder, then you have to make changes in index.php file like

**From:**

```html
require __DIR__.'../bootstrap/autoload.php'; 
$app = require_once __DIR__.'../bootstrap/app.php';
```

**to:**

```html
require __DIR__.'/bootstrap/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/bootstrap/app.php';
```

For your Js and CSS files, You have to add "public" before file path. Like asset("public/js/app.js"), asset("public/css/app.css")
Now your route /foo will work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have solved the problem. And what I did is just the same as you told me!